# Dependent checkboxes behaviour

Tags: user-expectation, checkboxes, toggle, intuition, representation

**Context:**

In a form, there are 2 main sections - Boosters and Filter.

If any Booster is checked, the Filter section cannot be checked and if filter is checked, no boosters can be checked. The current interaction is as below:

[image]

**Question:**
Is there a better way to represent and communicate this? There will only be one filter option. I feel like there's something wrong with the representation and layout. Should the filter option be a toggle above the boosters?

**How can I make this more understandable?**

Comment: I would make boosters *disabled* if i were to press filter, its simple and a very clear to the user what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

I suggest to add a top level selection between filter X or boosters using radio buttons. Then a secondary level underneath Boosters where they can be selected using checkboxes. If the Filter X radio button is selected, disable the Booster checkboxes.

Depending on whether you want a clear option to have neither Filter X nor Boosters you could add another radio button at the top saying 'No filters or boosters' and make that the default selection.

Comment: This is a decent solution but I think this isnt much different of the op's problem. I think going for something like **option B** from @renaud's answer would be best practise

Comment: I disagree with you @Tomm, Renaud is using checkboxes with non-standard behaviour which might confuse users. But that's my opinion, it's up to the Ashwin to choose and test a suitable solution.

Comment: Not to compare both designs, but I think Martyn's design is simple and clean (less is more). Only challenge is the default value. If context is clear, it would make this easier to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

[image]I suggest to clearly seperate Boosters and Filters if there are not compatible.

Here are 2 ideas :

**A**
with a tab system that force user to choose one group

**B** 
Separate vertically both categories and mentioning it is an **OR** choice

Comment: Option **B** is really clean and definitely tells you to choose either a booster or a filter. I think option **A** might be tempting or unclear to people resulting to try and select a booster and then a filter (even though they are seperate tabs).

Comment: I don't think tabs are typically used as a method of selection, but rather simply used for grouping or breaking up large amounts of data/settings. For example, if you right click and view properties of a file in Windows, it will open a window that shows categories of settings grouped in tabs. The user is allowed to modify settings in each tab, and click Save to preserve all of their modifications. In this case, the user might think "I've selected my Filter, now I'll continue on to select my Boosters." If they select the Filter tab, they'd have no visibility that their Boosters were deselected.